# Rails: how can I speed up rendering multiple youtube embedded iframes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails project, I need to load 10+ youtube videos (embedded iframes) per page. It's pretty slow even after implementing [lazy loading](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload), especially on mobile.

I was wondering if there's any 'trick' or something that I'm missing to make these iframes load (or appear to load) quicker. Right now, as the user scrolls down on mobile, they need to wait a few seconds before seeing anything.

Comment: Try to load the YouTube player resources once using their API https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#IFrame_Player_API and once it's downloaded during page loads, run JS functions to replace each of your HTML elements with the YouTube players that linked to individual video IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Found an amazing guide by Amit Agarwal to do exactly this:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

Basically you're loading images that look like youtube videos, and only rendering the youtube video if/when the image is clicked.